# How can I insert a row in SQLite and add 1 to the rows' IDs coming after it?

Tags: insert, android-sqlite

I have a table using an integer ID going from 1 to 300. Now I want to insert a row with ID 150, but I need that the current row #150 turns into row #151, #151 turns into #152 and so on. How can I do so?

Logical as it seems, this query won't work:

```
UPDATE mytable SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= 150;
```

Because SQLite cannot update any ID if the result happens to be an ID already in use, meaning 150 + 1 = 151, but there is already a row with ID 151 which should be changed next, but since it hasn't been changed yet, the present updating cannot be executed so nothing changes.

Can't use a loop either to update rows inverting its order since SQLite doesn't support them, neither can I use ORDER BY in an UPDATE query.

Last time I had to update rows one by one, starting from the end of the table. Any help?

Comment: **1** - `this query won't work`, `an UPDATE query` UPDATE is not a **query**, it's a **command**.  **2** - UPDATE doesn't INSERT new records. **3** Simply use AUTOINCREMENT on your id field. **4** Don't renumber your ids, leave them in peace. You'll get big pains if you do.

Comment: Why would you need an id to change? I don't see a valid reason for it. Usually it's an XY problem - in order to solve X, you're attempting Y (rewriting ids) but for the problem X there are better approaches, too.

Comment: OK. It's a command. :) I'm trying to do an update before inserting the row I need because `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (150, "other data")` is not working in spite of being autoincremented.
And I need to do so because that's what I've been told. Rows where inserted orderly and a row was missing, so it has to be ordered the same way. Otherwise when displaying the data, we would need to add a new column with some data indicating the order in which rows should be displayed and that's is far more work, since the app we are programming is already designed that way.

Comment: It's really **unclear** what are you trying to do and why. There's possibly a better solution.

Comment: Yes, there is: changing the app's logic, but that is not going to happen. I just need to insert a row and the other row's IDs to be addded 1. That's all.

Comment: It would be much better if you change your app's logic. My suggestion: let it happen. ;)

Comment: Ehm... Unfortunately I'm just a pawn in a company and they are not going to change the whole app's logic a week before the app is to be handed out.Nevermind, in the end I just did it manually.